# Не срабатывает message_hendler

Tags: python, telebot

Перестает работать на третьем вызове message_handler

```
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def welcome(message):

    chanel_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Сделать пост")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Пока ХЗ что сделать")
    chanel_markup.add(item1, item2)


    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать", {0}, reply_markup=chanel_markup)

    @bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
    def what_you_want(message):
        if message.text == 'Сделать пост':

            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton("канал1")
            item2 = types.KeyboardButton("канал2")
            item3 = types.KeyboardButton("какой-то третий канал")
            markup.add(item1, item2, item3)

            print("Перед вопросом")
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Для какого канал? \n\n1)канал1 \n2)канал2 \n3)какой-то третий канал", {0}, reply_markup=markup)
            print("После вопроса")

            @bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text']) #здесь перестает работать , ошибок в консоли нет

            def postmessage(message):
                print("Ответ поймал")
# RUN

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Для какого канал? \n\n1)канал1 \n2)канал2 \n3)какой-то третий канал", {0}, reply_markup=markup)
        print("После вопроса")

        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, postmessage)
```